# Does UITableViewController equal to UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could we use `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` totally replace `UITableViewController`, for example, is there difference between these two code lines?

```
@interface ShareViewController : UITableViewController
@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a BIG difference between these two lines of code.
This

```
@interface ShareViewController : UITableViewController
```

means that your ShareViewController inherits from `UITableViewController`, so it provides, for example, an `UITableView` as main view.
This

```
@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

means that your ShareViewController is a classic UIViewController (inherits from `UIViewController`) and simply implements protocols to manage table views.

Answer (score 1):

[UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) most importantly is a UIView **Controller**.

It implements `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols and has a `tableView` property/outlet (which is his only .view).

A UITableView is a **UIView**.

---

To get a `UIViewController` to do nearly everything a `UITableViewController` does for you, you have to implement the two protocols, drag a `UITableView` inside your `UIViewController`, create an outlet for it and set your `UIViewController` as the `delegate` and `dataSource` for your `tableView` outlet

You can add a `UIRefreshControl` to a `UITableViewControllers` `tableView` by just clicking a checkmark in StoryBoard for iOS6+, you have to write some more lines to do this on a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ShareViewController : UITableViewController
```

Above line means `ShareViewController` is inherits from `UITableViewController`

```
@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Above line means `ShareViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` & implements the `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` delegates

Answer (score 0):

If you check the reference for [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will see that it conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` but merely conforming to the same protocols does not make the classes equal. UITableViewController is a class suited for using with `UITableView`s where `UIViewController` can be used with any `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController` is a `UIViewController` already implemente `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` protocols, thus when you inherit your class with it you don't need to implement them in your `ViewController` again. It's like:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

To make it more clear, `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` are `protocols`, whereas `UITableViewController` is `ViewController`.